# How is the micropython's pyboard module generated from C implementation

Tags: module, micropython

There is a lot of pyboard module which can be use by micropython. Currently I just know that these module's real implementation is done in C. My question is:
How is the relationship mapped between the Python module and C implementation?
Such as we can use `import pyb`, where is the pyb Python file?
Such as we can use `from pyb import LED` and call the intensity function, where is the Python LED class definition? Where is the definition of its intensity function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to find this out is clone the [source code](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/) and then start looking around using whatever text/file search tool you prefer. Search for files/text 'pyb' and/or 'LED'. Then you'll find for instance [modpyb.c](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/stm32/modpyb.c) which defines the pyb module (in C, not in Python). There you can see the module's global dictionary has an entry

```
{ MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_LED), MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_led_type) }
```

which is MicroPython lingo to say 'there's a thing with the name LED and it is of type pyb_led_type. The latter being the the C code for the LED class and found in [led.c](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/stm32/led.c), including the `led_obj_intensity` function.

Comment: Hi,stijin,So thanks for your infomation. I also found a article for hacking MicroPython. https://github.com/PyConPL/Book/blob/master/2016/workshops/hacking_micropython/text.md